# update box stacking problem but all the height are same

Tags: dynamic-programming, lis

**The Box Stacking Statement:** Given n rectangle boxes, that the `i` box has height `h[i]`, width `w[i]` and depth `d[i]`. Create a stack of boxes that is the tallest one possible, but only can stack a box on top of another box if the dimensions of the 2-D base of the lower box are each strictly larger than those of the 2-D base of the higher box.

But in this problem, **all the boxes are has the same height (h[1]=h[2]=...h[n])** and `N <= 100000`. And we **don't need to rotate the boxes** anymore.

*Example:*

> n = 5
> w[]={1,3,5,7,9};
> d[]={5,7,4,6,8}
>
> The answer is: **3 ( [1x5] ; [3x7] ; [9x8] )**

I only can solve it in `O(n^2)` but I need less than it (can be `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve it with `O(n)`, because otherwise you would have an algorithm to sort `n` numbers in `O(n)`.

But you could solve it with `O(n log n)`.

1. First you need to sort with `w's` in ascending order. If you have two `w's` that are equals, sort in descending order by their `d's`.
2. Second you need to solve a `LIS` problem in the list of `d's`, and you will have you longest stack.

Please note that there are several approaches for `LIS` as far as I know, the `DP` approach is `O(n^2)`, but there are a `O(n log n)` approach which you can find one implementation and explanation(which I used) on [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/).

Here is my implementation of your problem with Kotlin:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println(
            maxTower(
                arrayOf(
                    intArrayOf(5, 4),
                    intArrayOf(6, 4),
                    intArrayOf(6, 7),
                    intArrayOf(2, 3),
                    intArrayOf(1, 1),
                    intArrayOf(2, 5),
                    intArrayOf(3, 5),
                    intArrayOf(3, 4),
                    intArrayOf(4, 4),
                    intArrayOf(4, 5)
                )
            )
        )
    }

    fun maxTower(blocks: Array<IntArray>): Int {
        if (blocks.isEmpty()) return 0
        blocks.sortWith(Comparator { o1, o2 ->
            if (o1[0] == o2[0]) {
                o2[1] - o1[1]
            } else {
                o1[0] - o2[0]
            }
        })
        val map = blocks.map { it[1] }
        return LIS(map)
    }

    fun ceilIndex(A: IntArray, l: Int, r: Int, key: Int): Int {
        var l = l
        var r = r
        while (r - l > 1) {
            val m = l + (r - l) / 2
            if (A[m] >= key) r = m else l = m
        }
        return r
    }

    fun LIS(A: List<Int>): Int {
        val size = A.size
        val tailTable = IntArray(size)
        tailTable[0] = A[0]
        var len = 1
        for (i in 1 until size) {
            if (A[i] < tailTable[0])
                tailTable[0] = A[i] else if (A[i] > tailTable[len - 1])
                tailTable[len++] = A[i]
            else
                tailTable[ceilIndex(tailTable, -1, len - 1, A[i])] = A[i]
        }
        return len
    }
}
```